Rows and pages within longtable
I have quite a large file with lots of scripts. The scripts are made using tables as shown in the code below.
An important part of the format of the book is that each set of text between the horizontal lines can't be split over a page. For example, step 11 below is great, but step 12 is not.

What I am wondering is if I can set up a new way of defining \nextstep so that all the \nextline's following are on the same page (if there are too many \nextline's then it automatically begins on a new page). Perhaps it is some type of counter that counts the number of \nextline's between each pair of \nextstep's and makes sure there is enough space, and if not it pushes it onto the next page.
The other challenge is we don't want to have the step/instruction headings at the top of each page, though we would like to start with a horizontal line.
Hopefully it is possible to automate this, though if not some advice around continuing the step numbers within a new table would be most helpful. Thanks so much!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry} 


% Define commands
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\step}{\thestep.\stepcounter{step}}
\newcommand{\scripttable}[1]{\vspace{-0.5cm}
\begin{center}
   \setcounter{step}{1}
   \begin{longtable}{rcp{17cm}}\toprule
      \textbf{Step} & & \textbf{Instruction}  #1
      \\ \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}}

\newcommand{\nextstep}{\\ \midrule \step & &}



\newcommand{\nextline}{\\ & & }
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\ss}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\signal}{\textcolor{black}{\texttildelow}}
\newcommand{\countwithme}{\ts{Count with me. }}
\newcommand{\myturn}{\ts{My turn. }}
\renewcommand{\check}{(Check. )}

\newcommand{\watching}{\tsi{Watching.\;}}
\newcommand{\tsi}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\scripttable{
\nextstep \ts{Let’s play a game called Race to 10.}
\nextline \ts{I will play against all of you.}
\nextline \ts{The first team to fill their ten frame and say “10 ones make 1 ten” is the winner.}
\nextstep \myturn \watching
\nextline (Place dice with \textbf{2} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{2}
\nextline \ts{I will make 2 on my ten frame.}
\nextline (Use counters to make 2)
\nextline \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones.} 
\nextstep \tsi{Your turn. \ts{I will roll for you this time.}}
\nextline (Place dice with \textbf{4} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{4}
\nextline \ts{Use your counters to make 4 \check}
\nextline \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones.} 
\nextstep \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.}
\nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{8}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 8 more to win.}
\nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{7} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{7}
\nextline \ts{I need to count out and pick up 7 counters.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.}
\nextline \ts{How many ones are on my ten frame?\signal} \ss{2 ones}
\nextline \ts{That’s right, I have 2 ones on my ten frame.}
\nextstep (Place counters on ten frame)
\nextline \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones, 8 ones, 9 ones.}
\nextline \ts{How many now?\signal} \ss{9 ones}
\nextstep \tsi{Your turn.}
\nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6.}
\nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{6}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 6 more to win.}
\nextstep \ts{I’ll roll for you.}
\nextline (Place dice with \textbf{3} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{3}
\nextline \ts{Count out and pick up 3 counters.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3.}
\nextline \ts{How many ones are on your ten frame?\signal} \ss{4 ones}
\nextline \ts{That’s right, you have 4 ones on your ten frame.}
\nextstep \ts{Place your counters on your ten frame.} \check
\nextline \ts{I want you to point to each counter and \tsi{count with me.}}
\nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones.}
\nextline \ts{How many?\signal} \ss{7 ones}
\nextstep \myturn
\nextline \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space).
\nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal}  \ss{1}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 1 more to win.}
\nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{5} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{5}
\nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
\nextline \ts{I need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
\nextstep \tsi{Your turn.}
\nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3.}
\nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{3}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 3 more to win.}
\nextstep \ts{I’ll roll for you.}
\nextline (Place dice with \textbf{9} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{9}
\nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
\nextline \ts{You need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
\nextstep \myturn
\nextline \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space).
\nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{1.}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 1 more to win.}
\nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{5} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{5}
\nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
\nextline \ts{I need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
\nextstep \tsi{Your turn. \ts{How many more do you need to make 10 ones?\signal}}
\nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3.}
\nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 3 more to win.}
\nextstep I’ll roll for you.
\nextline (Place dice with \textbf{3} facing up)
\nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{3}
\nextline \ts{Count out and pick up 3 counters.} \countwithme
\nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3.}
\nextline \ts{How many ones are on your ten frame?\signal} (Count if needed) \ss{7 ones}
\nextline \ts{That’s right, you have 7 ones on your ten frame.}
\nextstep \ts{Place your counters on your ten frame.} \check
\nextline \ts{I want you to point to each counter and count with me.}
\nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones, 8 ones, 9 ones, 10 ones.}
\nextline  \ts{How many?\signal} \ss{10 ones}
\nextline \tsi{Say after me,} \ss{10 ones make 1 ten!}
\nextline \ts{That’s right! You are the winners. Well done.}
\nextline \ts{Let’s play again. Clear your ten frame.}
\nextstep (Play Race to 10 three more times, with random dice results)
}

\end{document}


box them: use a multi-line tabular cell e.g. p{<width>} so you aren't starting a new row of the table each time. then start a new row at the end of each step.

you actually are using a multiline cell already - you just choose to start new rows mid-step. if you don't do that, the steps will stay together.

Use a multiline cell specification rather than starting new rows when you don't want material split. You define a multiline column with p{17cm}, but you always break the row, so you always get splits across pages.
I also removed the middle column. Perhaps you need this in your real document, but it did nothing here. Even so, 17cm is too wide, so I used 16.5cm instead.
longtable is centred by default, so adding center is only adding vertical space which you then try to remove with negative vertical space. Better not to use center and let longtable do its thing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\step}{\thestep.\stepcounter{step}}
\newcommand{\scripttable}[1]{%
  \setcounter{step}{1}%
  \begin{longtable}{rp{16.5cm}}
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \toprule
    \textbf{Step} &  \textbf{Instruction}
    \endfirsthead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    #1 \\
  \end{longtable}%
}
\newcommand{\nextstep}{\tabularnewline \midrule \step  &}

\newcommand{\nextline}{\newline }
\newcommand{\ts}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\ss}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\signal}{\textcolor{black}{\texttildelow}}
\newcommand{\countwithme}{\ts{Count with me. }}
\newcommand{\myturn}{\ts{My turn. }}
\renewcommand{\check}{(Check. )}

\newcommand{\watching}{\tsi{Watching.\;}}
\newcommand{\tsi}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\scripttable{%
  \nextstep \ts{Let’s play a game called Race to 10.}
  \nextline \ts{I will play against all of you.}
  \nextline \ts{The first team to fill their ten frame and say “10 ones make 1 ten” is the winner.}
  \nextstep \myturn \watching
  \nextline (Place dice with \textbf{2} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{2}
  \nextline \ts{I will make 2 on my ten frame.}
  \nextline (Use counters to make 2)
  \nextline \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones.}
  \nextstep \tsi{Your turn. \ts{I will roll for you this time.}}
  \nextline (Place dice with \textbf{4} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{4}
  \nextline \ts{Use your counters to make 4 \check}
  \nextline \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones.}
  \nextstep \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.}
  \nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{8}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 8 more to win.}
  \nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{7} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{7}
  \nextline \ts{I need to count out and pick up 7 counters.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.}
  \nextline \ts{How many ones are on my ten frame?\signal} \ss{2 ones}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right, I have 2 ones on my ten frame.}
  \nextstep (Place counters on ten frame)
  \nextline \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones, 8 ones, 9 ones.}
  \nextline \ts{How many now?\signal} \ss{9 ones}
  \nextstep \tsi{Your turn.}
  \nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3, 4, 5, 6.}
  \nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{6}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 6 more to win.}
  \nextstep \ts{I’ll roll for you.}
  \nextline (Place dice with \textbf{3} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{3}
  \nextline \ts{Count out and pick up 3 counters.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3.}
  \nextline \ts{How many ones are on your ten frame?\signal} \ss{4 ones}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right, you have 4 ones on your ten frame.}
  \nextstep \ts{Place your counters on your ten frame.} \check
  \nextline \ts{I want you to point to each counter and \tsi{count with me.}}
  \nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones.}
  \nextline \ts{How many?\signal} \ss{7 ones}
  \nextstep \myturn
  \nextline \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space).
  \nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal}  \ss{1}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 1 more to win.}
  \nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{5} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{5}
  \nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
  \nextline \ts{I need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
  \nextstep \tsi{Your turn.}
  \nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3.}
  \nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{3}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 3 more to win.}
  \nextstep \ts{I’ll roll for you.}
  \nextline (Place dice with \textbf{9} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{9}
  \nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
  \nextline \ts{You need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
  \nextstep \myturn
  \nextline \ts{Let’s count my empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space).
  \nextline \ts{How many empty spaces?\signal} \ss{1.}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. I need 1 more to win.}
  \nextstep (Place dice with \textbf{5} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did I get?\signal} \ss{5}
  \nextline \ts{Too many! Oh well.}
  \nextline \ts{I need to get exactly 10 ones to win.}
  \nextstep \tsi{Your turn. \ts{How many more do you need to make 10 ones?\signal}}
  \nextline \ts{Let’s count your empty spaces.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Point to each empty space), \ss{2, 3.}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right. You need 3 more to win.}
  \nextstep I’ll roll for you.
  \nextline (Place dice with \textbf{3} facing up)
  \nextline \ts{Which number did you get?\signal} \ss{3}
  \nextline \ts{Count out and pick up 3 counters.} \countwithme
  \nextline \ss{1} (Pick up counter for each number), \ss{2, 3.}
  \nextline \ts{How many ones are on your ten frame?\signal} (Count if needed) \ss{7 ones}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right, you have 7 ones on your ten frame.}
  \nextstep \ts{Place your counters on your ten frame.} \check
  \nextline \ts{I want you to point to each counter and count with me.}
  \nextline \ss{1 one} (Point to each counter), \ss{2 ones, 3 ones, 4 ones, 5 ones, 6 ones, 7 ones, 8 ones, 9 ones, 10 ones.}
  \nextline  \ts{How many?\signal} \ss{10 ones}
  \nextline \tsi{Say after me,} \ss{10 ones make 1 ten!}
  \nextline \ts{That’s right! You are the winners. Well done.}
  \nextline \ts{Let’s play again. Clear your ten frame.}
  \nextstep (Play Race to 10 three more times, with random dice results)
}

\end{document}


That is amazing, thank you!

@WendyTaylor you almost had the solution in your question. the setup was all done, really. you just needed to tweak the definitions not to keep starting new rows :-).
